# IE6 turns jar into zip

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-6, jar

Using windows server, I have a path to a file that, when you click the button, executes the jar file and runs the program.  At least in firefox.  The problem occurs with IE6.  It takes my file.jar and turns it into file.zip.  Any suggestions here?

Comment: haha while I would love to mandate the use of firefox, I've been informed by those higher then me that it needs to support both.  in fact at the moment I have a nice little text box that says use firefox, but I've been told it still needs to be fixed

Comment: JAR file is actually is a ZIP file (rename a JAR file to zip and it'll be opened easily with Winzip) change the JAR mime-type to "application/java-archive".

Comment: I knew about the similarity, I just have no clue how to fix it haha.  can you explain how exactly to change the mime type?  to be honest I don't usually mess around with html and servers and such, I'm just attempting to clean up someone else's stuff.  and if you make it an actual answer I can give you points...

Comment: You have to provide me information on what Windows Server you are running.

Comment: I actually had it as an answer but I deleted for fear of downvote. LOL. I've undeleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox can determine correct mime-type by extension first, and check header information to find out if there's a congruent match. IE6 unfortunately doesn't.

JAR file is actually is a ZIP file (rename a JAR file to zip and it'll be opened easily with Winzip) change the JAR mime-type to "**application/java-archive**".

**Update**

On IIS:

1. Select the site to configure in IIS, right click and select "Properties"
2. Under HTTP Headers Tab, select "File Types" under the MIME Map section and select "New Type"
3. Type "**.jar**" as the associated extension and "**application/java-archive**" as the content type.
4. Select "OK" and you're ready to go!
5. Restart IIS.

Comment: ok thanks that should be all I need.  I'm kind of disappointed this guy couldn't figure it out haha. Seems pretty simple.  However SO pulls through yet again =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an administrator set it in IIS on your web server, so that files served with the .jar extension use the "application/java-archive" mime-type.

In IIS6, right-click on the web site and choose "Properties". Go to the "HTTP Headers" tab, and in the bottom you'll see a section called "MIME Map". Click on the button "File Types" and add the following two types:

```
Extension: jar
Content-type: application/java-archive
```

In IIS7, you will see an icon called Mime-Types and click on that and then use the "Add" to add a new type.